# Unable to access apache2 web server on uap0 virtual interface from external client

Tags: apache-httpd

I have added a virtual interface **uap0** using the command

```
iw dev wlan0 interface add uap0 type __ap
```

on my raspberry pi running Raspbian Lite distro. The idea is that any user with the correct WiFi AP credentials must be able to connect to the AP and  access my web application. The WiFi AP is up and running. I have also configured **dnsmasq** as the DHCP & DNS server. I can connect to the AP successfully. **Unfortunately am unable to access the web application via**

```
http://192.168.5.50/index.html
```

Am using **hostapd** to manage the WiFi AP with the below configuration:

```
interface=uap0
ssid=MyAP
hw_mode=g
channel=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=mypass
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

**dnsmasq** configuration is as below:

```
bogus-priv
interface=uap0
no-dhcp-interface=lo,wlan0,eth0
bind-interfaces
dhcp-range=192.168.5.51,192.168.5.55,12h
```

The **apache2** is configured to bind and listen to **192.168.5.50:80**

**/etc/network/interfaces** contents specific to **uap0**:

```
# uap0 - Static IP Configuration
auto uap0
iface uap0 inet static
address 192.168.5.50
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.5.50
```

IPv4 packet forwarding is enabled via **sysctl.conf**

Please help!